# Как добавить изменение тега образа Docker в Bibucket Pipelines

Tags: docker, реестр, bitbucket, ci-cd, bitbucket-pipelines

У меня есть репозиторий Bitbucket и реестр Docker на JFrog. Я хочу, чтобы при каждом коммите новый образ автоматически собирался и пушился в реестр с новым тегом.
Так выглядит скрипт в файле bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
script:
  - docker login -u <my_login> -p <my_password> <my_registry>
  - docker image build -t test_image .
  - docker tag test_image <my_registry>/test_image:3
  - docker push <my_registry>/test_image:3
services:
  - docker
```

Проблема заключается в том, что теперь при каждом коммите образ собирается с тегом, указанным в скрипте (тут это 3). Как я могу сделать так, чтобы это значение увеличивалось на +1 с каждым новым коммитом? Если никак, подскажите, пожалуйста, другие способы решения проблемы :)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте переменную `$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER`:

```
  - docker tag test_image <my_registry>/test_image:$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
  - docker push <my_registry>/test_image:$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло